# Can't autowired field in interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to determine event when i store object in database. I use interceptor aproach.
Interceptor class looks like bellow:

```
public class TaskInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private TaskNoticeRepository taskNoticeRepository;// my repository class

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
}
```

Spring configuration file looks like bellow:

```
...<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="taskInterceptor" class="ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.interceptor.crm.TaskInterceptor"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.librait.cs.model,ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.dto.export"/>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="taskInterceptor" />...
```

When i build project I've got an error:

```
                    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.page.ActionPageService ru.librait.cs.controller.ActionController.actionPageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionPageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.model.repository.ActionRepository ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.page.impl.ActionPageServiceImpl.actionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory ru.librait.cs.model.repository.persistent.BaseRepositoryHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'taskInterceptor' while setting bean property 'entityInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.model.repository.crm.TaskNoticeRepository ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.interceptor.crm.TaskInterceptor.taskNoticeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskNoticeRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory ru.librait.cs.model.repository.persistent.BaseRepositoryHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.page.ActionPageService ru.librait.cs.controller.ActionController.actionPageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionPageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.model.repository.ActionRepository ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.page.impl.ActionPageServiceImpl.actionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory ru.librait.cs.model.repository.persistent.BaseRepositoryHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'taskInterceptor' while setting bean property 'entityInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.librait.cs.model.repository.crm.TaskNoticeRepository ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.interceptor.crm.TaskInterceptor.taskNoticeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskNoticeRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory ru.librait.cs.model.repository.persistent.BaseRepositoryHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 56 more
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created an hen-egg config (or cyclic dependency): To create the `sessionFactory`, you need the interceptor. The interceptor needs the repo. The repo needs the `sessionFactory`.

The most simple solution is to inject `ApplicationContext` and add a `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private TaskNoticeRepository taskNoticeRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    taskNoticeRepository = applicationContext.getBean(TaskNoticeRepository.class);
}
```

That moves this set up step a bit back and often works but it's brittle.

For things like that, I prefer to use "init beans" which I get from the app context when the app starts (in `main()` or a servlet context listener) which wire such dependencies after all beans have been created but before any "normal" code has a chance to run.

So there would be a lazy init bean which depends on the interceptor and the repo. The interceptor would get a setter for the repo. The bean would have a public `init()` method which would call the setter.

This avoids all kinds of "magic" set up code that might or might not work.

Comment: Can you share links for second approach?

Comment: No, you will have to read my answer carefully, understand the underlying concept and apply it to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is circular dependency , is bad design.. but you can try

```
  <bean id="taskInterceptor" class="ru.librait.cs.infrastructure.service.interceptor.crm.TaskInterceptor">
 <property name="taskNoticeRepository" ref="taskNoticeRepository"/>
   </bean>
```

and delete @Autowired
or add @Component annotation on TaskInterceptor  and delete bean declaration from xml

Answer (score 0):

If ApplicationContext too returns null implementing ApplicationContextAware solves the problem

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
LogsRepository repository = SpringContext.getBean(LogsRepository.class);
```